# Shiny reticulate app with a local package

Tags: r, shiny, reticulate

I have a shiny app that I'd like to deploy both on my own server and on shinyapps. I also have a custom python package not in any repository, but in a subdirectory within the main app directory. I want to load these packages with `reticulate`.

What's the best way to setup the virtual environment and make sure the custom package is installed?

```
reticulate::virtualenv_install("my_app_env", 
             packages = c('pandas','numpy', 'MYPACKAGE'))
```

Comment: AFAIK, you can just use `pkgload::load_all()` and point to the subdirectories which contain the custom packages. The reson this works is that there is no need to install those packages if you load them like this.

Comment: @GregordeCillia Sorry if it wasn't clear, these are python packages.

Comment: Use docker or some variant of that and have python packages included?